# Add UserControl2 to MainForm from programmatically added UserControl1 to MainForm

Tags: c#

I have a MainForm which has a panel. I have added a UserControl1 in it while start the application. by clicking a button inside of UserControl1 trying to call UserControl2 to add the panel and clear UserControl1 from main form panel. Then by clicking second button inside of UserControl2 trying to call UserControl1 and clear UserControl2 from main forms panel. But in my code when I call UserControl2 MainForm comes blank. what is the problem? here is code:

```
namespace UserControlTest
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form // main from
    {
        private static MainForm _instance;
        public static MainForm Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new MainForm();
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (!panel1.Controls.Contains(UserControl1.Instance)) // checking UserControl1 existance
            {
                panel1.Controls.Add(UserControl1.Instance); // add
                UserControl1.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Top; // dock it 
                UserControl1.Instance.BringToFront(); // bring to front of panel1
            }

        }

        public void CallUserControl1() // method helps to bring UserControl1 to front of panel 1
        {
            if (!panel1.Controls.Contains(UserControl1.Instance))
            {
                panel1.Controls.Clear();// clearing controls
                panel1.Controls.Add(UserControl1.Instance);
                UserControl1.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
                UserControl1.Instance.BringToFront();
            }
            else
            {
                UserControl1.Instance.BringToFront();
            }
        }
        public void CallUserControl2()// method helps to bring UserControl2 to front of panel 1
        {
            if (!panel1.Controls.Contains(UserControl2.Instance))
            {
                panel1.Controls.Clear();// clearing controls
                panel1.Controls.Add(UserControl2.Instance);
                UserControl2.Instance.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
                UserControl2.Instance.BringToFront();
            }
            else
            {
                UserControl2.Instance.BringToFront();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// first user control which helps to call UserControl2 to come front page

> ```
> public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
> {
>     private static UserControl1 _instance;
>     public static UserControl1 Instance
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             if (_instance == null)
>             {
>                 _instance = new UserControl1();
>             }
>             return _instance;
>         }
>     }
>     public UserControl1()
>     {
>         InitializeComponent();
>     }
>
>     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
>         mainForm.CallUserControl2();
>     }
> }
> ```

// second user control which helps to call UserControl1 to come front page

> ```
> public partial class UserControl2 : UserControl
> {
>     private static UserControl2 _instance;
>     public static UserControl2 Instance
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             if (_instance == null)
>             {
>                 _instance = new UserControl2();
>             }
>             return _instance;
>         }
>     }
>     public UserControl2()
>     {
>         InitializeComponent();
>     }
>
>     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         MainForm main = new MainForm();
>         main.CallUserControl1();
>     }
> }
> ```

Update: Thanks to comment of @RonBeyer this is worked but needed to clear controls of panel first than

```
var main = this.FindForm() as MainForm;
main.CallUserControl1();
```

Comment: Why are you using a singleton pattern for user controls? The problem is that you are creating a new `MainForm` and calling things on that, not the form that the control belongs to. If you want the form that this control is on, use `var main = this.FindForm() as MainForm;` instead of creating a new one.

Comment: thank you @RonBeyer that's worked.